# How to print a list without brackets

Tags: python

I have a list with float values. I want to remove the the brackets from the list.

```
Floatlist = [14.715258933890,10.215953824,14.8171645397,10.2458542714719]
print (", ".join(Floatlist))

but i am getting an following error :
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, float found
```

but i want to print the list like:

```
output:14.715258933890,10.215953824,14.8171645397,10.2458542714719
```

Comment: `", ".join(map(str, Floatlist))`

Comment: print str(FloatList)[1:-1] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.join` only operates on iterables that yield strings.  It doesn't convert to strings implicitly for you -- You need to do that yourself:

```
','.join([str(f) for f in FloatList])
```

---

<sup><sup>`','.join(str(f) for f in FloatList)` also works (notice the missing square brackets), but on CPython, it's pretty well known that the version with the list comprehension performs *slightly* better.</sup></sup>

Answer (score 5):

You need to convert the elements to strings.

```
print (", ".join(map(str, Floatlist)))
```

or

```
print (", ".join(str(f) for f in Floatlist)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You just make a for statement:

```
for i in Floatlist:
    print(i, ', ', end='')
```

Hope that helps

P.S: This snippet code only works in Python3

Comment: Please also mention that it is applicable only on python3+

Comment: But i dont want to convert float to string?

Comment: According to the documentation, all objects are converted to strings (using str() function), then they are written to the stream.

Answer (score 1):

Just to print:

```
print(str(Floatlist).strip('[]'))
#out: 14.71525893389, 10.215953824, 14.8171645397, 10.2458542714719
```