# How to print a number list without the brackets and with formatting in Python

Tags: python, list, formatting

My question is a continuation of
[Print list without brackets in a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178061/print-list-without-brackets-in-a-single-row)
and
[How to print a list without brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39146973/how-to-print-a-list-without-brackets)

From the second question I would like to be able to print a specific format, similar to using

```
print(f'{10.1234567:.2f} units')
```

So from

```
Floatlist = [14.715258933890,10.215953824,14.8171645397,10.2458542714719]
print (", ".join(map(str, Floatlist)))
```

we get

```
14.71525893389, 10.215953824, 14.8171645397, 10.2458542714719
```

but I would like to get

```
14.72, 10.22, 14.82, 10.25
```

or even

```
14.72 units, 10.22 units, 14.82 units, 10.25 units
```

Again, using a single line of code, as the above questions

Ps. I know that putting the units in the `', '` as `' units, '` we will not get the units on the last item.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.format` with `str.join`:

```
Floatlist = [14.715258933890,10.215953824,14.8171645397,10.2458542714719]
print( ', '.join( '{:.2f} units'.format(v) for v in Floatlist ) )
```

Prints:

```
14.72 units, 10.22 units, 14.82 units, 10.25 units
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to change the `map` operation, to a more precise one

```
floatlist = [14.715258933890,10.215953824,14.8171645397,10.2458542714719]
print(", ".join(map(lambda x : str(round(x, 2)), floatlist))) # for only 2 decimals

print(", ".join(map(lambda x : f'{x:.2f} units', floatlist))) # for 2 decimales + 'units'
```

---

Note : [Function and variable names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names)